# There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null". Как реализовать аутентификацию в приложении без шифрования пароля bcrypt

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-jpa

У меня есть метод аутентификации

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(personDetailsService);
    }
```

Я пытаюсь создать свой кодировщик без использование хэширования

```
@Bean
public static PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить эту ситуацию. Это учебный проект, и я не хочу использовать здесь bcrypt. Мне нужно проверить данные в нехешированном виде